# How efficient is the YEAR(date) function?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to search a table with millions of records for all records where

```
YEAR(ACTIVITYDATE) = some integer
```

I can add an index over ACTIVITYDATE and then apply the YEAR function to my filter.

However, wouldn't I be better off storing a computed column ACTIVITYYEAR that is persisted where the column is defined as YEAR(ACTIVITY) and have and index over ACTIVITYYEAR?

I know that if there aren't enough distinct values over an indexed column in the table, SQL will do a table scan anyway. I don't yet have enough data to perform tests, and I trying to define the table layout, as much as I can, now.

Your thoughts?

Comment: Whats your alternative? String manipulation?

Comment: Not sure if I follow. I don't think casting as strings is going to improve performance. Probably the opposite. My choices are one of the two presented above, unless there is another option I am unaware of.

Comment: why don't you try views?

Comment: @Chad. I wasn't suggesting String's I was merely saying that there aren't many alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to have a computed column to "search a table" for rows that match one year. Write you where clause using an interval instead and have an index on your date column.

```
select SomeColumn
from YourTable
where ActivityDate >= '20110101' and
      ActivityDate < '20120101'
```

If you want to use an int (year) as argument to the query instead of two strings you can use `dateadd`. Just make sure that you don't apply any functions/manipulations to the ActivityDate column because SQL Server won't be able to use the index if you do.

```
declare @Year int = 2011

select SomeColumn
from YourTable
where ActivityDate >= dateadd(year, @Year-1900, 0) and
      ActivityDate < dateadd(year, @Year-1899, 0)
```

Comment: That is also an option (which I did consider suggesting). Reason I didn't was the sometimes need to watch out for time portions of datetimes when comparing a range...

Comment: @MitchWheat - Yes, the time usually is a bother when using `between` because it is inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Create a computed column on `ACTIVITYDATE` and then index that:

```
create table aTest
(
   id int not null,
   activityDate datetime null, 
   computedYear as YEAR(activityDate)
)

create nonclustered index NC_TEST on aTest(computedYear)
GO

insert into aTest (id, activityDate) VALUES (1, '2011/010/18')
insert into aTest (id, activityDate) VALUES (2, '2011/010/06')
insert into aTest (id, activityDate) VALUES (3, '2011/010/23')
```

Ref.: [Creating Indexes on Computed Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx)

If you have few distinct dates, then you could also create a [filtered index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) to make it's use more likely.

Answer (score 1):

It is better for performance to use the computed column and then index it.