# SQL select * from column where year = 2010

Tags: sql

This is probably a simple where clause but I want to say, from columnX (which is datetime) I want all rows where just the year = 2010.

so:

```
select * from mytable where Columnx =
```

Comment: Some extra info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870943/how-efficient-is-the-yeardate-function

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
select * from mytable where year(Columnx) = 2010
```

Regarding index usage (answering Simon's comment):

if you have an index on Columnx, SQLServer WON'T use it if you use the function "year" (or any other function).

There are two possible solutions for it, one is doing the search by interval like Columnx>='01012010' and Columnx<='31122010' and another one is to create a calculated column with the year(Columnx) expression, index it, and then do the filter on this new column

Comment: If the performance is not up to scratch, i think this method doesnt make use of any indexes on the `Columnx` column

Comment: @simon - You are right, wrapping a column in a function makes it non-sargable. This results in a full scan. I would not ever do this. It is very poor practice for filtering dates.  I highly recommend the OP looks at your answer.

Comment: Hi @simon, thanks for you comment, I added more explanations on the matter. I just didn't do it before because since the OP is having very simple issues with a Year() function, I didn't imagine he would be worrying about indexes usage at this point.

Comment: @Demns, appreciate your comment, but saying things like "I would never do that" is also relative. We don't know the OP's reality. Maybe he is querying a "holidays" tables that has only dozens of rows. Silly example, I know, but It could be real. So, do you really think he needs to worry about this detail in such a small table?

Comment: @Diego - Point taken. I still would do it Simon's way, as I believe that keeping to certain best-practices in *all* cases means you can rely on getting it right when necessary. `>= X and < Y` covers you from alsorts of unexpected logical and performance problems.

Comment: I agree @Diego, your answer is definately correct, I just wanted to try and alleviate any future issues he may have.

Answer (score 37):

If i understand that you want all rows in the year 2010, then:

```
select * 
  from mytable 
 where Columnx >= '2010-01-01 00:00:00' 
       and Columnx < '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: +1 - Does what the OP wants ***and*** makes use of indexes for a range seek, which can be orders of magnitude faster than the other answers here so far.

Comment: Yes, +1 for allowing the use of indexes. You could also simplify the condition to: `where Columnx >= '2010-01-01' and Columnx < '2011-01-01'` (without any difference in efficiency, just a few characters of code less :)

Answer (score 8):

T-SQL and others;

```
select * from t where year(Columnx) = 2010
```

Comment: Wrapping a column in a function makes it non-sargable. This results in a full scan. I would not ever do this. It is very poor practice for filtering dates.  I highly recommend the OP looks at @simon answer.

Answer (score 1):

its just simple

```
  select * from myTable where year(columnX) = 2010
```

Comment: Wrapping a column in a function makes it non-sargable. This results in a full scan. I would not ever do this. It is very poor practice for filtering dates.  I highly recommend the OP looks at @simon answer.

Answer (score 0):

NB: Should you want the year to be based on some reference date, the code below calculates the dates for the `between` statement:

```
declare @referenceTime datetime = getutcdate()
select *
from myTable
where SomeDate 
    between dateadd(year, year(@referenceTime) - 1900, '01-01-1900')                        --1st Jan this year (midnight)
    and dateadd(millisecond, -3, dateadd(year, year(@referenceTime) - 1900, '01-01-1901'))  --31st Dec end of this year (just before midnight of the new year)
```

Similarly, if you're using a year value, swapping `year(@referenceDate)` for your reference year's value will work

```
declare @referenceYear int = 2010
select *
from myTable
where SomeDate 
    between dateadd(year,@referenceYear - 1900, '01-01-1900')                       --1st Jan this year (midnight)
    and dateadd(millisecond, -3, dateadd(year,@referenceYear - 1900, '01-01-1901')) --31st Dec end of this year (just before midnight of the new year)
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL

```
select * from mytable where date_part('year', Columnx) = 2010
```