# mysql need to show all months data for the selected year

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I got stuck with my query. I need to show monthly (current + previous) records.

Let's take below example for the year 2014:-

I have 7 records in the month 03(March)

I have 2 records in the month 04(April)

So total records in the year 2014 is 9.

Now we come to the year 2015:-

I need to show all records in Jan(No new records added in the database), This should be 9.

**My Query shows 0.**

I need to show all records in Feb(5 new records added in the database), This should be 14.

**My query shows 5.**

*Query works fine when I am checking for month 03 and year 2014, showing all 7 records. but not for all conditions.*

> I am calling the same query for fetching all months(01-12) data one by one.

```
SELECT count(pkID) as TRecords 
FROM   students 
WHERE  (fkCategoryID ='56' 
OR     fkSecondaryCategoryID ='56' 
OR     fkOptionalCategoryID ='56') 
AND    MONTH(`DateAdded`) <='1' 
AND    YEAR(`DateAdded`) <='2015';
```

Comment: Is this similar to :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891025/sql-select-from-column-where-year-2010

Comment: I will check, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AND    MONTH(`DateAdded`) <='1'
```

Think about this. You won't find a month smaller than 1. Year and month belong together; don't look at them separately.

```
SELECT COUNT(pkID) as TRecords 
FROM students 
WHERE (fkCategoryID = 56 OR fkSecondaryCategoryID = 56 OR fkOptionalCategoryID = 56)
AND DATE_FORMAT(DateAdded, '%Y%m') <= '201501';
```

Comment: Great, This may be a solution. I will try this

Comment: Do so :-) I think to stringify year and month is the simplest solution. If you wanted to use `year()` and `month()` instead, that would be something like `where year(dateadded) < 2015 or (year(dateadded) = 2015 and month(dateadded) <= 1)`.

Comment: WHERE MONTH(`dateadded`) <='1' AND (YEAR(`dateadded`) ='2015' OR YEAR(`dateadded`) <'2015') fails

Comment: Of course it does. I told you there is no month smaller than 1.

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(DateAdded, '%Y-%m') <= '2015-01'; gives same results for all months

Comment: This is fine, I was checking 2015-1 instead of 2015-01. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In you where clause, you are doing <= (less than or equal to).  I expect you want just = (equal to) for your year and month.  Certainly your year should only be = (equal to).

Comment: Please read my question, If I will use equal to then this will check only for given month and year not previous