# How to display 2015 instead of 2015-01-02-13455032 in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to simplify my return results in SQL Server.

I have a table with a column `Date`, with data that look like this `2015-01-01 00:07:43 -06:00`.

How can I get the output to show the column data just for 2015?

I thought something like this would work, but I don't think I have right syntax.

```
SELECT [table] 
WHERE date = '2015%'"
```

where anything after 5 doesn't matter. I just want anything with 2015 to show.

Thank you!

Comment: Note: Don't use the accepted answer. Use the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9891089/2029983) with proper date boundaries.

Comment: If you want to *display* just the year you can use `SELECT YEAR(date)`, if you want to filter then you can use `WHERE date >= '20150101' AND date < '20160101'`